# Set relative location header with Restlet

Tags: http-headers, restlet, restlet-2.0

When trying to set a relative location header using something like the following code:

```
setLocationRef(getReference().addSegment(MyItem.getId()).getPath());
```

Restlet seems to always make the Location header an absolute URL no matter what I do. It there a way to override this behavior and set a relative URL in the Location header? Besides creating a filter to edit the raw headers, that is.

Comment: I've now actually tried to edit the header via a filter, but this doesn't work. I tried calling the following in the `afterHandle` of a filter that the resource is attached to: https://gist.github.com/mafuba/8498646. It appears, however, that the header does not yet exist at that point. It seems Restlet does not turn the location reference set in `setLocationRef` into a header until just before sending the actual response. I think I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at the http RFC, I read that the Location header is an absolute URI:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: Hi Thierry, I am aware of the specification. I also know that [modern clients will accept and utilize relative location headers, and that the draft of the next version of the spec allows relative headers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31274/what-are-the-consequences-for-using-relative-location-headers#31337). Thus my question is not whether I _should_ do it, but how I _can_ do it. :-)